# Showing a list of workbooks opened in a ListBox without .xlsx

Tags: vba, excel

I've created multiple UserForms which open different workbooks. In order to know the workbook opened when I activate a UserForm, I've created a ListBox `ListBox2` to show the user what workbooks are opened. Here is the code:

```
With Me.ListBox2
    For Each wkb In application.Workbooks
        .AddItem wkb.Name
    Next wkb
End With
```

But the workbooks shown have their extensions. Meaning that there is `.xlsx` in every workbook listed on the `ListBox2`.

How can I remove these extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways I can think of -use INSTRREV to find the last dot.  This will everything to the left of the '.' including the path if it's there.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print FileNameOnly("mdl_FILE_Functions.bas")
End Sub

Public Function FileNameOnly(ByVal FileName As String) As String
    FileNameOnly = Left(FileName, InStrRev(FileName, ".") - 1)
End Function
```

Or Scripting.FileSystemObject to return the base name.  This will just return the file name and remove the path and extension.

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetBaseName("mdl_FILE_Functions.bas")
End Sub

Public Function GetBaseName(FileName As String) As String
    Dim FS As Object
    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    GetBaseName = FS.GetBaseName(FileName)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Left` function, and then the `InStr` function to find the length of the workbook name before the extension.

```
Dim wb_name As String
wb_name = ThisWorkbook.Name
MsgBox (Left(wb_name, InStr(1, wb_name, ".xls") - 1))
```

In your scenario:

```
With Me.ListBox2
    For Each wkb In application.Workbooks
        .AddItem Left(wkb.Name, InStr(1, wkb.Name, ".xls") - 1)
    Next wkb
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the extension part by using the left(String, numChars) function on the string.

```
.AddItem left(wkb.Name,len(wkb.Name)-4)
```

This will work for *.xls? extensions. You might want to consider checking for the last '.' within the filename as this will help you eliminate *.xls file as well (should they occur).

Answer (score 0):

```
.AddItem Split(wkb.Name, ".")(0)
```

or FSO:

```
.AddItem CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(wkb.Name)
```